# Close Console Tab in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to close a tab opened in lightning Console using lwc,

just like how we use workspace API in Aura lightning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other dev says it is not supported in lwc but you can do it by wrapping your LWC component in an Aura component.
I am here with working example where we are sending and event from child lwc to parent aura component. Code is self explanatory and very simple if some know basics of lwc and aura, still have any issue let me know.
**Create lwc childWebComp first so write Html and js for it.**

```
<!-- childWebComp.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Close tab" icon-name="utility:chevronclose" icon-position="right" onclick={handleButtonChange}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

Its JS file that fire an event.

```
//  childWebComp.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class CategoryFilter extends LightningElement {     
    handleButtonChange(){ 
    var close = true;
        const closeclickedevt = new CustomEvent('closeclicked', {
            detail: { close },
        });

         // Fire the custom event
         this.dispatchEvent(closeclickedevt); 
    }

}
```

Now write parent Aura component and controller to changed event

```
<!-- ParentAuraComponent.cmp -->
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" >

    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default="Close Not Clicked"/>
    <!-- your Workspace api tag should be there to make it work -->
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/> 


    <lightning:card title="AuraDomEventListener" iconName="custom:custom30">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <span class="aura">Aura Component</span>
        </aura:set>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning:layout>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="4">
                     <!-- This is an LWC component -->
                    <c:childWebComp oncloseclicked="{!c.handleFilterChange}"/> 
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="8" class="slds-p-left_medium">
                    {!v.message}
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

```
//ParentAuraComponentController.js
({
    handleFilterChange: function(component, event) {


        var CloseClicked = event.getParam('close');
        component.set('v.message', 'Close Clicked');


        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Lightning web components do not support Lightning Console or Workspace API as of now . You have to wrap an aura component around your lwc to suppport this.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences

Comment: Here is a solution using workspace API in LWC: https://mtr-design.com/news/salesforce-mini-how-to-open-a-subtab-in-console-from-lightning-web-component