# Unable to close tab with Aura/workspace API

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, workspaceapi

I've read that the only way to close a Salesforce console tab in lightning experience is via the workspace API using Aura ([Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/260474)).

I've tried to implement the provided [sample code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_closeTab.htm) but it doesn't work, per my understanding, when running the code below it should close the tab immediately. However it does not work and I'm not sure why as I don't see any error in the console.

What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
// CloseTab.cmp
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />  

</aura:component>



//  CloseTab.controller

({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```